# Appending HTML to parent from inside iFrame without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm developing in an application where new code is introduced via iframes only.  I'm trying to create a function (running inside an iFrame) that will append some html after the iFrame in which it is running.  I'd rather not introduce jQuery to resolve this issue.  Here is a sample

```
    function AppendDivAfteriFrame() {
        var iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementById(window.frameElement.id)
        var newDivInParent = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
        newDivInParent.setAttribute("Id", "MyDiv");
        newDivInParent.innerHTML = 'Hello World!  I am outside the iFrame';
        iFrame.appendChild(newDivInParent);
    }
```

I don't receive any exceptions, but I never see any results either.

## Update with full code

Call this page InnerPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppendDivAfteriFrame() {
            var iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementById(window.frameElement.id)
            var newDivInParent = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
            newDivInParent.setAttribute("Id", "MyDiv");
            iFrame.appendChild(newDivInParent);
            parent.document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello World! I am outside the iFrame';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="AppendDivAfteriFrame()">Append HTML</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Call this page OuterPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="InnerPage.html" id="MyiFrame"></iframe>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Straight off, can you confirm that the iframe belongs to the same website as the host page - that is, same domain name and same port?  If it doesn't, there's certainly no way such an operation would be allowed (for web security reasons)

Comment: Yes.  And for testing purposes I've mocked up a simple website project with only the outter page and inner page and it's still not working.  That should eliminate any issues related to the application I'm eventually hoping to develop this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works:**

```
function AppendDivAfteriFrame() {
     var iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementById(window.frameElement.id)
     var newDivInParent = window.parent.document.createElement('div');
     newDivInParent.setAttribute("Id", "MyDiv");
     iFrame.parentNode.appendChild(newDivInParent);  //Edited here
     parent.document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello World! I am outside the iFrame';           
}
```

Comment: Same issue.  Please note that when I was cleaning up the code to post here I made a mistake and called my variable newDivInParent in one place and newDiv in another.  I've corrected that in my original question, and corrected it in your code before trying as well.

Comment: I tried doing that before posting.  I'm not really sure how to fiddle this one.  Fiddle runs inside an iFrame anyway, but they restrict cross frame scripting so I can't access the outer page.  I don't know how I would create two pages in a fiddle to demonstrate this.

Comment: U hav other option put it on git hub.  or give us a demo link

Comment: I've included full code above.  Let me know if it's insufficient.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in acceptance.  I hadn't noticed your update.  Thank you so much!